# EF Core with Oracle using DB First

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, mapping, ref-cursor

I have an existing App with its most of the logic written in Oracle DB SProc using ref cursors and I choose EF with its mapping over classic ADO.NET with something like Automapper. First I want to know if that's the best practice in this case or not second I got stuck in a point where ref cursors don't return any result if there's no result to the query which makes the mapping throws mapping exception so how to check on that ?

Here's how I define the ref cursor

```
prmRefCursor.ParameterName = "refCursorParam";
prmRefCursor.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
prmRefCursor.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
sprocParamsList.Add(prmRefCursor);
```

And then I call the the Procedure

```
_dbContext.orders.FromSqlRaw
```

Comment: Something incompatible here. Oracle's Refcursor and EF Core. How do you use such SPs with EF?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I define the ref cursor as one of the parameter and define it as output then run the procedure with <DBSET>.FromSqlRaw

Comment: More clear now. Not sure how to solve that. Debugging. Or create custom function which intercepts such exception and returns empty list.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv that's what I'm looking for, how to intercept EF core to disable mapping in case of empty list or switching to ADO.NET if there's no other way

Comment: Update question with exception details.